# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01002: fetch out of sequence

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I have one demo application to check select for update query

```
public class Test implements Runnable{

    public Test() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Test());
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Test());

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{
            String updateWith = "";
            String sel = "SELECT SIDNUMBERTO FROM tblmserialbatchdetail WHERE sidnumberto = ("+
            "SELECT max(sidnumberto) FROM tblmserialbatchdetail WHERE generationmode='A' and nvl(serialprefix,' ') = nvl('',' ') " +
            "and sidlengthwithoutprefix =12) FOR UPDATE";
            //System.out.println("SELECT QUERY ===: "+sel);
            String updatequery = "update tblmserialbatchdetail set sidnumberto = ? where serialbatchid = ?";
            System.out.println();
            Connection connection = Conn.getDBConnection();
            PreparedStatement pStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sel);

            ResultSet rSet = pStatement.executeQuery();

            while(rSet.next()){

                updateWith = rSet.getString(1);
                long value = Long.parseLong(updateWith)+1;
                updateWith = String.valueOf(value);
                System.out.println("resulet To be Updated ===> "+value);
            }
            connection.commit();
            connection.close();



        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

This works fine if i remove For update from select query otherwise give me error

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01002: fetch out of sequence

    at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:180)
    at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTIoer.processError(TTIoer.java:208)
    at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.Oall7.receive(Oall7.java:543)
    at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTC7Protocol.doOall7(TTC7Protocol.java:1451)
    at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTC7Protocol.fetch(TTC7Protocol.java:943)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteQuery(OracleStatement.java:2119)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:2324)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:421)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:365)
    at com.response.Test.run(Test.java:47)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`SELCT ... FOR UPDATE` only makes sense in the context of a managed transaction, since it requires locks to be taken out on the selected rows.

By default, JDBC does not use a managed transaction, it uses an implicitly created one that commits as soon as the query is executed. This will break the semantics of `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`, and the JDBC driver complains.

In order to use a managed transaction, add

```
connection.setAutoCommit(false);
```

before you execute the query. Afterwards, execute `connection.commit()`.

Comment: Yes it works but now process stoped at line   ResultSet rSet = pStatement.executeQuery();

Comment: @chetan: Probably because it can't take out the lock, because something else has already locked it. Impossible to say for sure.

Comment: Yes, it worked on setting auto commit to false. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I got the ORA-01002: fetch out of sequence issue with Spring JPA- Native SQL, for ORACLE MERGE statement.

Issue is with hibernate session, I fixed it passing my datasource to jdbctemplate.
Excluding Spring JPA native SQL and migrating to JDBC template resolved issue for me. I got issue only for ORACLE Merge statement and not for other SQL queries.

@Bean
    public JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate() throws Exception{
        Map dataSources = applicationContext.getBeansOfType(DataSource.class);
        Objects.requireNonNull(dataSources, "Data Source is required");

```
    DataSource dataSource = dataSources.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(entry->entry.getKey().startsWith("abc"))
            .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
            .findAny().orElseThrow(()-> new Exception("DataSource ABC is required."));

    return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
connection.setAutoCommit(false);
```

As a general note, 'select ... for update' is not the best locking strategy.

Comment: can u please provide alternative ?

Comment: How can I  possibly provide alternative if I don't know the problem you're trying to solve? :)

Answer (score 0):

instead of using executeQuery, you can use executeUpdate function.
Do not use "select for update" instead directly try to update the rows in one transaction, This will give you the updated rows count. This way for example when two transaction tries to update a row , first one wins other returns zero and you know that first succeeds to update since it will return updated rowcount.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use @Modifying for DML queries when using @Query

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).