# SQL Error ORA-01002 not autocommit and loop

Tags: c++, sql, c, oracle

I'm using pro c/c++ in a unix environment. Inside a c function I create a simple select statement which is not inside a loop and autocommit is disabled.

This is the dynamic sql;

```
char sql_statement[200];
int num1, num2;

...
snprintf(sql_statement, sizeof(sql_sattement), "select column1, column2 from '%s' where num = '%d' and code_cfg = '%d'", "customer", 0, 0);

exec sql prepare instruction_to_execute from :sql_statement;
exec sql declare crs cursor for instruction_to_execute;
exec sql open crs;
exec sql fetch crs into :num1, :num2;
...
```

Executing this code gives me ORA-01002 error. As I said before, this code is not inside a loop and autocommit is off.

But if I write this code statically, works fine. Below the code:

```
EXEC SQL
    SELECT column1, column2
    INTO :num1, :num2
    FROM CUSTOMER
    where num = 0
        AND code_cfg = 0;
```

SQL instruction is simple. For my understanding this code should be executed fine.

In SO I found some answers:

[ORA-01002: fetch out of sequence C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28756339/ora-01002-fetch-out-of-sequence-c)

[ORA-01002: fetch out of sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26707896/ora-01002-fetch-out-of-sequence)

[Hibernate error “ORA-01002” when persisting entity with custom Sequence Generator](https://web.archive.org/web/20150501072557/http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27532374/hibernate-error-ora-01002-when-persisting-entity-with-custom-sequence-generato)

[ORA-01002: fetch out of sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16215711/ora-01002-fetch-out-of-sequence)

[java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01002: fetch out of sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906998/java-sql-sqlexception-ora-01002-fetch-out-of-sequence)

Comment: This error is presented due to your cursor being out of range. whilst you say you don't use a loop this is what the cursor is doing. Reading further it looks the be the fetch after that is the issue, scroll down to bottom of the page : http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_01002_fetch_out_of_sequence.htm

Comment: @Dane Ok. This select returns 1 row only. In this case, how can I populate my variables?

Comment: Ok. This sattement returns 1 row only. In this case how can I populate my variables?